# Get Resource Image and Use As JFrame Background

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I would like to ask for some help taking a resource image, and setting it as the background of the JFrame. I want to scale the image to be centered in the frame. How can I do this? I have looked on Google for answers, but nothing that I read makes any sense to me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See the examples cite in [tag:embedded-resource] info.

Comment: `but nothing that I read makes any sense to me` - why do you think anything we suggest will be any different that what you have already seen? There are only a couple of standard approaches to do what you want. Did you look under the "Related" heading on the right of this page for ideas. `I want to scale the image to be centered in the frame`. That requirement doesn't make sense to me. Usually you scale an image to fill the frame or you leave the image at its original size and then center is within the frame. What does scale and center mean to you?